# TypeError: can't pickle _thread._local objects quando tento usar RFE do scikit-learn em um modelo criado no tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, sklearn

Estou tentando usar o RFE da biblioteca scikit-learn em modelos que criei usando tensorflow, porém quando tento treinar recebo `TypeError: can't pickle _thread._local objects`. Segue o código e o erro abaixo:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE

data = {'atributo1':[1,2,3,4,5],'atributo2':[1,2,3,4,5],'atributo3':[1,2,3,4,5],'atributo4':[1,2,3,4,5], 'target':[1,0,1,0,1]}

base = pd.DataFrame(data)

n_hidden1 = 100
n_hidden2 = 50
n_outputs = 2

def create_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_hidden1,activation = 'relu'),
                             tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_hidden2,activation = 'relu'),
                             tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_outputs,activation = 'softmax')])
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model

model = tf.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn.KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model(), batch_size = 10, epochs = 20)
rank = RFE(estimator=model,verbose=1,n_features_to_select=2)
rank.fit(base.drop('target',axis=1),base['target'])

> runfile('C:/Users/panto/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/panto/.spyder-py3')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-5-4d89fbeba90e>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/panto/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/panto/.spyder-py3')

  File "C:\Users\panto\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\panto\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/panto/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 25, in <module>
    rank.fit(base.drop('target',axis=1),base['target'])

  File "C:\Users\panto\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_selection\rfe.py", line 144, in fit
    return self._fit(X, y)

  File "C:\Users\panto\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_selection\rfe.py", line 179, in _fit
    estimator = clone(self.estimator)

  File "C:\Users\panto\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 64, in clone
    new_object_params[name] = clone(param, safe=False)

  File "C:\Users\panto\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 55, in clone
    return copy.deepcopy(estimator)

  File "C:\Users\panto\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\copy.py", line 180, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)

  File "C:\Users\panto\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\copy.py", line 280, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)

  File "C:\Users\panto\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)

  File "C:\Users\panto\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)

  File "C:\Users\panto\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\copy.py", line 169, in deepcopy
    rv = reductor(4)

TypeError: can't pickle _thread._local objects
```

Comment: Você precisa fitar o modelo antes de a função `RFE`, não?

Comment: Não, já usei RFE com modelos criados no próprio sklearn e funcionou assim, ele serve justamente para fitar várias vezes e encontrar o rank dos atributos.

Comment: Tente fazer um exemplo mínimo replcável. Pq aí ficaria mais fácil entender o que está acontecendo. Ver instruções aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu código está certo, mas ele não está rodando e nem vai rodar porque existe uma incompatibilidade entre o `Keras` e a função `RFE` (recursive feature elimination ) do `sklearn`. Como pode ser visto na [documentação](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFE.html) da RFE:

> Primeiro, o estimador é treinado no conjunto inicial de recursos e a
>   importância de cada recurso é obtida através de um atributo **coef_** ou
>   através de um atributo **feature_importances_**. Em seguida, os recursos
>   menos importantes são removidos do conjunto atual de recursos. Esse
>   procedimento é repetido recursivamente no conjunto podado até que o
>   número desejado de recursos a serem selecionados seja finalmente
>   alcançado. (Tradução livre, ênfase minha)

Ou seja, para que a RFE funcione, o modelo subjacente utilizado deve ter um atributo que se chama `coef_` ou um que se chama `feature_importances_`. Note que esse não é o caso do `KerasClassifier`. Você pode ver isso usando o seu próprio código com algumas modificações. Veja:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
from sklearn.svm import SVR #esse modulo vai ser importante para o próximo exemplo

data = {'atributo1':[1,2,3,4,5],'atributo2':[1,2,3,4,5],'atributo3':[1,2,3,4,5],'atributo4':[1,2,3,4,5], 'target':[1,0,1,0,1]}

base = pd.DataFrame(data)

n_hidden1 = 100
n_hidden2 = 50
n_outputs = 2

def create_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_hidden1,activation = 'relu'),
                             tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_hidden2,activation = 'relu'),
                             tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_outputs,activation = 'softmax')])
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model

X = base.drop('target',axis=1).values
y = base['target'].values
model = tf.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn.KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, batch_size = 10, epochs = 20)
model.fit(X, y)

#Mostrar todos os métodos e atributos
print(dir(model))
```

Esse é o output, note a ausência dos atributos citados na documentação do RFE:

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_keras_api_names', '_keras_api_names_v1', 'build_fn', 'check_params', 'classes_', 'filter_sk_params', 'fit', 'get_params', 'model', 'n_classes_', 'predict', 'predict_proba', 'score', 'set_params', 'sk_params']
```

Ou simplesmente:

```
print('coef_' in dir(model))
print('feature_importances_' in dir(model))
```

Output:

```
False
False
```

Para ver que seu código funciona e o problema é o `Keras`, rode o mesmo código utilizando um modelo `SVR` linear. Para isso, basta importa o módulo (ver código acima), e substituir o `model` por:

```
model = SVR(kernel="linear")
```